# MVC Validate and post to controller with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am kind of new to jquery ajax. I am tring to learn client side jquery validation without using the DataAnnotations. when I press the login button the page refreshes doesn't post to the controller's Login(User x) method using the ajax post. I am not a expert any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

My model

```
public class User
{
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost]
    public bool Login(User x)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public ActionResult LoginTst()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The view is LoginTst & the script

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#signin").click(function ()
        {
           
                $("#loginForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        UserName: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 2,
                            maxlength: 15
                        },
                        Password: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 5,
                            maxlength: 18
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        UserName: {
                            required: "username req",
                            minlength: "user is small",
                            maxlength: "user is long"
                        },
                        Password: {
                            required: "pass req",
                            minlength: "pass is small",
                            maxlength: "pass is long"
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        var form = $('#loginForm');
                        $.ajax({
                            cache: false,
                            async: true,
                            type: "POST", 
                            url: form.attr('Login'), // the action it 
                            data: form.serialize(),
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data == false) {
                                    alert("Username doesn't exist");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                });

            });

        
    });
```

```html
<form action="" name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="UserName" name="UserName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="Password" name="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit" id="signin">login</button>
        </div>   
     </form>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: your action isn't set to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your action is not set.  You could set it manually or you can wrap your input fields with an Html.BeginForm.  The latter allows you to reference your controller as well as a method on your controller without being worried about the relative path.

Here is an example:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new {@id="loginForm"}))
{   
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="UserName" name="UserName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="Password" name="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit" id="signin">login</button>
    </div>  
}
```

Of course, you could use [HTML Helpers](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/787320/an-absolute-beginners-tutorial-on-html-helpers-and) for the input controls inside the using block as well.

You also need to update your `submitHandler` to pull in the action as generated by the form helpers:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
  var form = $('#loginForm');
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: form.attr('action'), // the action as defined in the <form> 
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == false) {
        alert("Username doesn't exist");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

You can find a working dotnetfiddle example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kRfSnh

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am tring to call the ajax post in my script

Comment: @abarthelot Updated my answer.  It's still related to the Action attribute but also needs to be updated in your `submitHandler`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I tried your way and the validation stops working

Comment: no worries.  there were two syntax errors: missing an '@' before the using statement and missing a quote for when declaring the login form ID.

Comment: I fixed them when i tried it but it's still not working :(

Comment: I added a link to a dotnetfiddle site at the bottom of my answer using what we talked about above.  Please compare to yours to figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: even there an alert with "Username doesn't exist" doesn't show, i think that is be cause it is not using the submitHandler, instead it is using the default form submit

Comment: That is a completely different problem in that your `bool Login(User x)` method isn't returning a valid JSON result: `False` instead of `false`.  There is a new dotnetfiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WBWuWs with that issue fixed and it works just fine.

Comment: thanks for putting up with me, that is what i wanted :), Sorry if i took you on a wild goose chase

Answer (score 1):

You're setting URL to `form.attr('Login')`, but in your HTML, form does not have a "Login" attribute.

What you probably want to do is set the action on the form (to the url you want), and change the url in the javascript to use form.attr('action').

Comment: I added action="@Url.Action("Login", "LoginController")" in the form and the validation doesn't work. when i remove it the validation works again, i even tried  $("#loginForm").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(e);
            and added the ajax post here});
this calls the action method in the controller but refreshes the page

Comment: Try changing "LoginController" to just "Login".
Did you also change your javascript from url: form.attr('Login') to url: form.attr('action')?

Comment: Yes i did and i checked in the debugger it calls the action method i want but it is not using the submitHandler, it is using the form default submit which calls the action method from 'action' attribute.